# Is there a "Resharper-like" addin for MonoDevelop?

Tags: resharper, monodevelop

I've googled and not come up with much.  Has anyone run across something like Resharper for Mono?

Comment: Will probably come to nothing but CodeBetter started a Twitter hashtag for pledging money for a MonoDevelop Resharper version http://twitter.com/#search?q=%23pledgetoresharperformonodevelop

Comment: @Ben - Saw that yesterday.  My hope is that it will come to fruition, but I am afraid you're right.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, no. A few people have discussed it but nothing concrete has emerged. We've been trying to implement some of the low-hanging fruit among the R# features that matter to people, such as the camelCase completion list matching - please file enhancement bugs if you can think of any more!

Also, now that MonoDevelop is no longer GPL there's the possibility that JetBrains could actually implement a R# addin for MD, if there's enough demand. R# as whole is immensely complex, so I don't imagine anyone else could build a decent equivalent any time soon.

UPDATE: There is an experimental Resharper-like source analysis and quick fix feature built into MonoDevelop 3.0. It can be enabled in Preferences.

Comment: Thanks - I was your blog today.  I discovered it after you posted at somewebbuy this morning.  Haven't had a chance to watch your screen casts but have them on the to do list.  I'm really excited by the MonoDevelop is taking.

Comment: Source Analysis -> Enable analysis of open files